# Как из тега выбрать часть текста по условию?

Tags: python-3.x, beautiful-soup, текст, tag

имеем html документ:

```
   ...
        html_doc = <td class="gScore">2 : 0<br /><span>(7-6<sup>6</sup>, 7-5)</span></td>
   ...
```

нужно получить текстовые данные из тега td, исключая текст в теге `<sup>`,
т.е.: "2 : 0(7-6, 7-5)"

сейчас я обращаюсь непосредственно ко всему тегу и работаю с ним как со строкой:

```
td_info = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(html_doc.text, 'html5lib')    
score = str(td_info.find('td', class_='gScore'))
```

соответственно получаю:

```
       "<td class="gScore">2 : 0<br /><span>(7-6<sup>6</sup>, 7-5)</span></td>"
```

далее, используя текстовые операторы получаю нужный результат. :|

я уверен, это можно сделать как-то проще. :)

Comment: питон ругается на эту строчку - SyntaxError: invalid syntax.  Подозреваю, что исправив синтаксис мы получим данные включая текст из тега sup. я как раз хочу избавиться от этой цифры "6"

Comment: score = td_info.td['gScore'].text

Comment: ошибка KeyError: 'gScore'

Comment: score = td_info.find('td', class_='gScore').text А так?

Comment: используя метод text получим - score = '2 : 0(7-66, 7-5)'. я как раз хочу избавиться от второй шестерки

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = '<td class="gScore">2 : 0<br /><span>(7-6<sup>6</sup>, 7<sup>6</sup>-5, ' \
           '6-4, 13<sup>24</sup>-11<sup>20</sup>)</span></td>'
td_info = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "xml")

# будут удалены все теги "sup" в td_info
[x.decompose() for x in td_info.select("sup")]
print(td_info.text)
```

вывод

```
2 : 0(7-6, 7-5, 6-4, 13-11)
```

Comment: я не указал, что тегов может быть несколько и сама строка может быть сложнее, например:
html_doc = '<td class="gScore">2 : 0<br /><span>(7-6<sup>6</sup>, 7<sup>6</sup>-5, 6-4, 13<sup>24</sup>-11<sup>20</sup>)</span></td>'

Comment: меня интересует, можно ли как-то исключить данные в теге sub при обработке тега td?

Comment: @another_one_minsk Обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо, очень помогли